# Getting a PortType and Binding different with wsdl

Tags: asp.net, binding, wsdl, asmx, porttype

I got a wsdl file and I use the wsdl.exe tool to convert it to a C# interface.
Everything is ok but :
In the output description (myurl.asmx?wsdl) I got those lines :

```
<wsdl:binding type="tns:myWebServicePort" name="myWebServicePort">
...
</wsdl:binding>
```

And

```
<wsdl:service name="myWebService">
    <wsdl:port name="myWebServicePort" binding="tns:myWebServicePort">
    <wsdl:port>
<wsdl:service>
```

And finally, in my interface, I got :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute( Name = "myWebServicePort", Namespace = "http://services/" )]
```

For me it's ok, but not for who use my web service.
They are waiting those informations :

```
<wsdl:binding type="tns:myWebService" name="myWebService">
...
</wsdl:binding>
```

And

```
<wsdl:service name="myWebService">
    <wsdl:port name="myWebServicePort" binding="tns:myWebService">
    <wsdl:port>
<wsdl:service>
```

And I'm unable to get this.
With the name on my WebServiceBindingAttribute I can only have myWebservice either myWebServicePort. But not both.

Are they any ways to get this ?
I found some infos on other questions but it's for WCF...

Thanks in advance for your help.

M.